# Show that $\int_0^\infty e^{-st}e^{-\lambda t}dD(t) = e^{-sT}e^{-\lambda T}$

Tags: integration

where D(t) is the degenerate distribution at T:

$D(t)=   \begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $ t\lt T $} \\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Thanks!

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the definition of an integral with respect to a dirac-measure at $T$. You could write it as:
$\int_0^\infty f(t) dD(t) = \int_{\{T\}}f(t) dD(t)+\int_{(0,\infty)\setminus\{T\}}f(t) dD(t)$

Now in the first expression you are integrating the constant value $f(t)$ at $T$ (constant because $t$ can only take the value $T$ on that set) over the set {$T$} the measure of which under your dirac measure is 1, so you get $f(T)\cdot\delta_T(\{T\})=f(T)\cdot1=f(T)$. The second term is a integral over a set of zero-measure, so it evaluates to $0$ now matter what $f$ is and you get your desired result.